How can I decide direction of normal vector when parametric surface integral?
surface interal with parameters can be expressed like:
$  \iint_{S} \vec F \cdot d \vec S = \iint_D \vec F \cdot \vec n dS $
But I think that $\vec n $ can vary if using cross product because $\vec n $ can be calculated as $ \vec n = \frac{ r_u \times r_v}{\vert  r_u \times r_v \vert }$,  also $ \vec n = \frac{r_v \times r_v}{\vert r_v \times r_u \vert } $
, but these directions are relatively different.
How  can I choose $\vec n$ from there two?

I suggest that you have a look at my last question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5009353/1135547
